# Synaptic Package Manager interface is in Thai language. How do I change it to English?

Tags: kubuntu, launcher, language-support, synaptic

When launched from Launcher, my SPM (Synaptic Package Manager) interface is in Thai.  Konsole outputs a lot in Thai but its interface is English (It's Application Language Setting is set to English). System Language Setting is English with Thai also installed but second in order.

```
cat /etc/default/locale
```

gives:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="th_TH.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="th_TH.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="th_TH.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="th_TH.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="th_TH.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="th_TH.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="th_TH.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="th_TH.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="th_TH.UTF-8"
```

Just

```
locale
```

gives 3 additional lines:

```
LANGUAGE=en_US:th
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

In a terminal,

```
synaptic
```

results in SPM in Thai

```
LANG=en_US synaptic
```

results in SPM in English

```
synaptic-pkexec
```

,which is the Launcher command, results in SPM in Thai

```
LANG=en_US synaptic-pkexec
```

results in SPM in Thai

Comment: There are 2 posts very similar to this.  This is not a duplicate because those problems were caused by the system language not being the one desired.  I've shown that my system language is the one I want to appear in my application clearly in my question.

Comment: Compare `cat /etc/default/locale` with just `locale`. And you may want to add a tag of KDE or Kubuntu.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks for the tip. I did it and the results are added to my question.  How do I interpret them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Launch **System Settings**
2. in the **Personalization** section select, **Regional Settings**
3. select **Language**
4. select Thai click the left arrow moving it back to **Available Languages** and leaving English as the only **Preferred Language**
5. Logout and login

The SPM menus now appear in English.
locale
now results with the Language line changed:

```
LANGUAGE=en_US
```

I can still type in Thai in all my applications.  The system language setting changes the languages used in the system and in applications, not the languages available to keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the settings of `LC_*` variables in `/etc/default/locale`, i.e. remove all the lines but the two first. If you want Thai formats to be present in other applications, you can use *Language Support* to set it *without clicking the "Apply System-Wide" button*.

Comment: I tried commenting out (by putting a # in front of) the LC_* variables and rebooting.  There was no change in the application behavior.  I don't have a _"Apply System-Wide"_ button in my _Language Support_.  Perhaps we have different systems.  I'm using Kubuntu.

Comment: @HolyHarmonica: I see. Yes, _Language Support_ is a tool used in other Ubuntu flavors, but Kubuntu does it the KDE way. I understand from your own answer that you figured it out yourself. Great!

Comment: Your comment made me think to look at the system settings again.  Which made me consider that there might be a difference between language settings and keyboard settings.  Thanks for reading my question and commenting.